# Searching for Root-mode SSH Server for 64 bit Android v5 and above

Tags: android, ssh

I have used QuickSSHD as an SSH server on several Android devices, but with the arrival of Android 5.1 and 64-bit operating systems, it seems **it doesn't work anymore**.

Both QuickSSH and SSHDroid yields an `only position independent executables PIE supported` error message. Icecold SSH Server works, but it does not allow for root access nor configuring the standard 22 TCP port.

What **SSH Server** could I use that allows? :

- Root access.
- Configure any TCP port.
- Works on 64 bit Android 5.1 or later.

Open Source solutions preferred.
Free, if not open source, accepted.
Paid versions, if not possible, accepted too.

This [thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9905/is-there-some-ssh-server-for-android) at Android's StackExchange reports about some SSH servers, but I have tested all of them and they don't work (or I have not been capable to make them work), possible due to the 64 bit issue, or they are not root-capable.

Full list of tested programs until now:

- Quick SSHD.
- SSHDroid.
- SSH Server (IceCold).
- Servers Ultimate Pro.
- DigiSSHD.
- Rooted SSH/SFTP Daemon.
- SSHelper.
- SSHD Manager (not tested: it requires OpenSSH).
- SimpleSSHD.

Comment: I cannot tell about the 64bit requirement, but just give a short pointer: my short list of [SSH Servers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_sshclients#group_388) might be a starting point. Looks like many projects are not that active anymore :)

Comment: Thanks you, @Izzy , but none of them works. I have added them to my list in the original post. Your second server says `openssh daemon needs to be preinstalled like in CM` (this is, Cyanogen Mod). I don't use Cyanogen Mod. Maybe you would have a link on installing such OpenSSH Daemon?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but a vague idea of how that could be accomplished: As you have root access, install a [Busybox](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_991) binary which supports SSHD. Some of them have Dropbear integrated, which is a lightweight SSHD. You might need to start that from the command line then. For binaries, [also see here](http://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.21.1/).  If a "how-to" is needed, that better fits on Android.SE then :)

Answer (score 1):

My workaround (the main problem is not fully solved):

- [SSHelper](http://www.arachnoid.com/android/SSHelper/index.html)
- Any **port forwarding** tool

**SSHelper**:

- Solves the problem of **root access** for remote **SSH login consoles** and has a very good shell (some others don't even have TAB completion).
- Works fine on **Android 5.1**. Most of the others yield (as for today, September 2015) a `PIE Error` on the code (supposedly for the 64 bits matter).
- However, does not allow for standard **22 TCP** port.

The **port forwarder** tool (I prefer the payment **[Servers Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimatepro&hl=es)**, but there are many others free):

- Redirects (forward) the **22 TCP port for incoming** connections to your configured (**2222 TCP** default) internal port.

The two programs **together** save the day.
By the way, both of them must be running at the same time.

The rest of programs refered to in the original question have more unbearable problems.